# If a subset $X$ of a $C^k$ manifold $M$ is semialgebraic in the charts of $M$, is it Whitney stratifiable?

Tags: stratifications, semialgebraic-geometry, o-minimal

Let $M$ be a $C^k$ manifold for some $k\geq 1$ and $X$ be a subset of $M$.

Assume that there is an atlas of charts $(\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha)_\alpha$ of $M$ such that in the coordinates of each of these charts, the intersection $X\cap U_\alpha$ of $X$ with the domain $U_\alpha$ of the chart is semialgebraic.
As was shown by Thom (I believe), this implies that $X\cap U_\alpha$ is Whitney stratifiable in $M$ (i.e. it admits a stratification that satisfies Whitney's conditions).
My question is: does this imply that $X$ as a whole is Whitney stratifiable ?

It is not entirely trivial (as far as I understand), because though you can find an appropriate stratification in each chart, you would have to carefully glue the strata from various charts together to construct a global stratification.

Nonetheless, I have a strong suspicion that it is true, and furthermore that it should be common knowledge for anyone who works with Whitney stratifications, but I could not find such a statement in the literature.

In case it changes something : in the specific problem on which I am working, $M$ is a vector bundle over a compact manifold and only a finite number of charts $(\phi_\alpha, U_\alpha)_\alpha$ are needed to cover it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !